# What is the motivation of VQ-VAE?

Tags: variational-autoencoder

I don't understand the motivation because I read that the motivation for VAE was that: ['it could be shown that it is not meaningful to interpolate the latent space of regular auto-encoders'](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73) (my own paraphrasing) and apparently VAEs were meant to fix that.

But now with [VQ-VAEs](https://paperswithcode.com/method/vq-vae) it seems once again that it is not meaningful to interpolate the latent space? Please correct me if I'm wrong but exactly what benefits does VQ-VAE have over regular auto-encoders?

Comment: empirically speaking, vector quantization it has been shown to be very helpful in deep learning in many scenarios.. it's not as clear why is that, but my opinion is because you are removing unnecessary noise... at the end of the day, your aim is to create a generative model, not a interpolation model that can pass from any image to any other image, so if you are only interested in generation, you are better off optimizing only for that